# All words of PHP variable from mysql database are not coming in Input field of HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my web application, I am trying to add a "Edit button" option to enable a user to change his information which he has already submitted. "Edit button" trigger a Modal with edit form which is pre-filled with values from Mysql database (provided by user at the time of registration).

But complete value of variables is not coming in input fields.
For example: Originally user filled his name as Asheesh Kumar which is saved in the database but edit form input field shows only first word of the name "Asheesh".

HTML code below:

```
<div class="col-md-4 ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value=<?php echo $Name; ?>>
</div>
```

What I am getting in Input field:
[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFj6b.png)

its happening for all Input fields in Edit form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well.. hard to tell without any code. But, I would start checking the following:

1. The variable is really coming complete from the database?
2. The html input does have a maxlength attribute?
3. If you're using javascript to set the input value, are you escaping the especial characters to avoid any javascript error?

## Update

After the update in question (that was missing the code), I could notice that the problem is because you're not opening and closing the quotes of the `value` atribute of your `input` field.

You should change this:

```
<input ... value=<?php echo $Name; ?>>
```

To this: (note the closing " of the value attribute)

```
<input ... value="<?php echo $Name; ?>">
```

Comment: <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" maxlength="50" value=<?php echo $Name; ?>>
</div>

Comment: Yes, when I echo the same variable somewhere else, it comes full.

Comment: I am not using JS for it

Comment: @AsheeshKumar, you need to start and close the quotes of the value attribute. 

Example: `<input ... value="<?php echo $Name; ?>">`

Comment: @AsheeshKumar, did it work? If so, would you please select this as accepted answer/solution? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, now its working. You solution was perfect.

Answer (score -2):

Only two possible error you have made.

1. Most probably your MySQL Type Length
2. As for the HTML Input Field, instead of using input use Text Area when you call out value from database.

Comment: MySQL type - Text, length - 100